# Multiple dialogs. How to detect which one is focused?

Tags: javascript, angular, dialog, primeng

There are multiples dialogs at the same time in my application and each of them have their own shortkeys, so i need to know if it's being used to execute correctly these shortcuts.
For example: if i hit 'esc' key, only the focused dialog must close.

How to detect which dialog is being focused?

Edit

---

I've made a testing demo to make the scenario easier to understand:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/multiple-dialogs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way!

Here it is for whoever needs:

```
import { DomHandler } from 'primeng/api';
import { Dialog } from 'primeng/dialog';

@ViewChild('dialog') dialog: Dialog;

isDialogFocused() {
  if (parseInt(this.dialog.container.style.zIndex) == DomHandler.zindex) {
    console.log(this.dialog.header + " is focused!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [hasFocus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hasFocus) to detect which one is focused

Comment: hasFocus() works only for the entire page. I couldn't find out how to use it to detect dialog focus. It's useful to detect which tab/page is focused. Or am i wrong? Thanks!